# How to add a scrollable table in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: 11.04, libreoffice

I want to copy/paste a table from LibreOffice Writer that is two pages long into LibreOffice Impress BUT I want it to be shown inside one slide. In this slide I will have the ability to scroll the table so I can show the rest of the table.

Right now if I copy the table over it goes outside the slide size and goes all the way down so the rest of the table is not shown in the slide show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert the table inside a `floating frame`:

1. Menu `Insert` -> `Floating Frame`;
2. Enter Name and description;
3. In `contents`, select the odt document containing the table.

This will result in a frame with scrollable content. I think you can't c&p the table into the frame, but you could save it to a separate odt if you don't wan't to show the complete odt that originally contains the frame.

Editing / modifying the frame is a little bit complicated - the frame may get updated (after changing its size, e.g.) only after entering the properties menu and leaving it again without doing any changes. Furthermore, selecting the frame using the mouse seems impossible. Instead, use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate between the slide's content elements.